# BigQuery - Query Name, Key and Value

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a query in BigQuery.

My table looks like this. So there are a lot of events of show_in_detail and I want to access the ID (1234) and the name (Blablabla) of all events accumulated over a specific date sorted by the most popular ID in descending order. How do I do this?

```
+----------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
|   event_name   | event_params.key | event_params.value.string_value | 
+----------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
|show_in_detail  | id               | 1234                            |
|show_in_detail  | name             | Blablabla                       |
+----------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
```

I tried:

```
SELECT event_params.key FROM `tablename_and_date` LIMIT 1000
```

But got the error:

> `Cannot access field key on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING,
>   value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value
>   FLOAT64, ...>>> at [1:21]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT param.key, param.value.string_value 
FROM `tablename_and_date`,
UNNEST(event_params) param
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! It almost works so I mark your answer as correct. I still get results that are not key or value though and they aren't sorted. So what I'm thinking of (which is not working) is to add like:
WHERE param.key = "id" OR param.key = "name"
SORT(descending)

And COUNT(nr of times a specific ID appears and show the result)

Comment: the current question is answered as it was. this would be your next question - feel free to post with all new details and we will answer :o)